# JavaScript only works on index.html in a Django web app

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, function

I recently started to integrate JavaScript into my Django projects. However, I am facing an issue: Whenever I try to animate an  element by clicking on a button it works fine in the index.html but not on other templates that extend the *layout.html*. I am new to JavaScript so I couldn't trace back the roots of the problem. Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/anime.min.js' %}"></script>
    <title>Meine Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ball"></div>
    <button id="btnwow">Animieren</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**layout.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/anime.min.js' %}"></script>
    <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**thoughts.html**

```
{% extends 'website/layout.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="ball"></div>
    <button id="btnwow">Animieren</button>
{% endblock %}
```

**script.js** (in the same folder with anime.min.js)

```
function animateStart(){
            anime({
                targets: '#topbar',
                translateY: [-500, 0],
                easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
                opacity: [.1, 1],
                duration: 1500
            });
            anime({
                targets: '#introduce',
                translateX: [-500, 0],
                easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
                opacity: [.1, 1],
                duration: 1500
            });
        }
function init(){
    function aufdecken(){
            anime({
                targets: '.offer',
                opacity: [0,1],
                delay: anime.stagger(100),
                duration: 2000,
            });
        }    
        function pendeln(){
            anime({
                targets: '#ball',
                translateX: [-500, 0],
                easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
                opacity: [.1, 1],
                duration: 1500
            });
        }
var button = document.getElementById('ein');
button.addEventListener('click', aufdecken)

var btn = document.getElementById('btnwow');
btn.addEventListener('click', pendeln)
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', animateStart);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("books/", views.books, name="books"),
    path("schlaf", views.schlaf, name="schlaf"),
    path("thoughts", views.thoughts, name="thoughts")
]
```

My goal is to call the function *pendeln* in my JavaScript file as soon as I click the button (id="*btnwow*") in my *thoughts.html* file. As mentioned above it works fine in the index.html but not in the extended *thoughts.html*.
Thank you for your help. I would appreciate it.

Comment: have you tried copy/pasting the `<div id="ball"></div>  <button id="btnwow">Animieren</button>` html directly into the thoughts.html file, replacing the `block` tags to test?  Also in your browser inspector, when you visit your site/thoughts, in the network tab, do you see the javascript file loaded?

Comment: @ja408 Thank you for your answer. Yes, I tried to copy it straight without the blocks. Both css files are shown in the network tab. But now I get the following error: "script.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at HTMLDocument.init (script.js:37)" Of course JS doesn't find an element with the id="ein" in the thoughts page because there isn't one. Is the order of functions relevant to JS code? Does it stops as soon as an error occurs?

Comment: I found the solution. It was crucial to put the btn.addEventListener **before** the button.addEventListener in the JS file. It seems like JS didn’t execute the rest of the init function because it couldn’t find the element of the variable „button“…

Comment: ah yes, of course!  JS reads top to bottom.  If the function that is being called wasn't loaded before it reaches the JS that calls the function, it will not know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was crucial to put the `btn.addEventListener` **before** the `button.addEventListener` in the JS file. It seems like JS didn’t execute the rest of the init function because it couldn’t find the element of the variable `button`